# Is there an easy way to replicate MySQL data?

Tags: mysql, replication, java, architecture

My software is deployed in various cities, each have a database, but they have different authorizations such as:

```
              central DB
                 /\
                /  \
              DB1  DB2
              /\    /\
             a  b  c  d
```

Databases `a` & `b` need replication to `DB1`.  Databases `DB1` & `DB2` need  replication to `central DB`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are the schema names and table names unique on each of a, b, c, and d?  Or are they the same?  What is the nature of the access needed to the data on DB1, DB2, and central DB -- read-only or do updates need to go back upstream to a/b/c/d (which I'm assuming are the sources of the data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions

## Commercial Product

There is a product called [**ScaleBase**](http://www.scalebase.com/solution/) that can handle Geographic replication topologies.

## Handcrafted Solution

If you want to set up Geographic Replication using MySQL Replication, you will need to make the MySQL Instance in each Data Center resilient. Here is what thinking:

#### IDEA #1 : Local Data Redundancy

In each city, setup DRBD with MySQL running on the DRBD Primary

#### IDEA #2 : Use Distribution Masters

Having a MySQL Replication Master handle the traffic of SQL statement between Data Center could possibly add some intermittent behavior in terms of Replication Lag. If you run another MySQL Instance within the same Data Center whose sole purpose is to ship binary logs to another Data Center, that can be setup in what some call a BLACKHOLE slave. That MySQL Instance contains no actual MySQL. It simply has binary logs and relay logs sued for shipping to multiple slaves. [**I have discussed using this type of Slave in StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273043/mysql-in-star-topology/5784578#5784578).

#### CAVEAT

The two ideas can be combined. The only drawback for using IDEA #2 is doing `ALTER TABLE`. If any major changes are to be done to table layouts, make sure the Distribution Masters do not change from the [**BLACKHOLE Storage Engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) because this could cascade to the other Data Center and possibly destroy data.

## EPILOGUE

I wrote about setting up such topologies before

- `Aug 20, 2012` : [Best solution for cross-datacenter MySQL master-slave replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22788/best-solution-for-cross-datacenter-mysql-master-slave-replication/22790#22790)
- `Aug 20, 2012` : [How to use MySQL Server 5.6 for GeoIP replication?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22730/how-to-use-mysql-server-5-6-for-geoip-replication/22791#22791)
- `Jun 25, 2012` : [Mysql database replication on different vlan/subnet/another site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21474/mysql-database-replication-on-different-vlan-subnet-another-site/21477#21477)
- `Dec 19, 2011` : [Best way to setup master to multi master replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/best-way-to-setup-master-to-multi-master-replication/9425#9425)
- `Dec 17, 2011` : [Mysql Master-Master Replication Topologies on >2 machines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9328/mysql-master-master-replication-topologies-on-2-machines/9336#9336)
- `Aug 18, 2011` : [With MySQL Replication, what level of resilience is possible?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/with-mysql-replication-what-level-of-resilience-is-possible/4769#4769)
- `Jun 01, 2011` : [What can we do in MySQL 5.0 Replication to address bandwidth concerns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-can-we-do-in-mysql-5-0-replication-to-address-bandwidth-concerns/3107#3107)
- `Mar 29, 2011` : [MySQL high availability, failover and replication with Latency](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/mysql-high-availability-failover-and-replication-with-latency/1983#1983)

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: A multi-tiered synchronization like that is something that [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) can do. It's open source and works with MySQL, along with many other databases. It is backed by [JumpMind](http://www.jumpmind.com) if you need a GUI setup and professional help.

Comment: thank you @RolandoMySQLDBA ,the two ideas are very useful to me .

Comment: thanks. Have you ever use SymmetricDS ,I ever found somebody recommand it.