# How Much Resources Does the BLACKHOLE Storage Engine Consume？

Tags: mysql, replication, storage-engine

I'm going to add a MySQL Relay Slave which use BLACKHOLE Storage Engine.

The relay slave will just filter some databases binlog to downstream slave.

Our MySQL Master generates about 15G a day in binlogs.

How much CPU and Memory will be enough for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a relay slave (a.k.a. Distribution Master) is using nothing but the [**BLACKHOLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) storage engine for application tables, you really should not have to tune anything for MyISAM or InnoDB since there are no data or index pages to cache.

You will have a nominal amount of disk I/O (mostly reads) since the `.frm` file for every BLACKHOLE is still accessed for metadata purposes. This same behavior also happens to MEMORY tables. I wrote a post about this. [I helped the person asking the question realize that dropping and creating MEMORY tables created disk I/O](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/i-am-using-the-memory-storage-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk-why/2876#2876).

I presume you are not going to drop and add tables all that often since the relay slave needs to remain all BLACKHOLE. Nevertheless, CPU and Memory should not be a big factor on a relay slave. You should be concerned with the following on the Relay Slave:

- Sufficient Disk Space for Binary and Relay Logs
- Fast Enough Disk for Writing
- Setting [sync_binlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sync_binlog)=1 in `my.cnf` for flushing binlogs thoroughly
- Rotation of Binary Logs (setting a proper [**expire_logs_days**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days))
- Avoid replicating the following:

  - storage-engine specific `ALTER TABLE` statement that BLACKHOLE can't work with
  - `ALTER TABLE` statements not accepted by BLACKHOLE, InnoDB, and MyISAM
  - creating tables with `ENGINE=InnoDB` or `ENGINE=MyISAM` because you want all tables in the relay slave to remain BLACKHOLE.

I have addressed this scenario before

- `Aug 20, 2012` :  [How to use MySQL Server 5.6 for GeoIP replication?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22730/how-to-use-mysql-server-5-6-for-geoip-replication/22791#22791)
- `Jun 01, 2011` : [What can we do in MySQL 5.0 Replication to address bandwidth concerns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-can-we-do-in-mysql-5-0-replication-to-address-bandwidth-concerns/3107#3107)

## UPDATE 2014-08-11 11:47 EDT

**Additional Clarification** : A pure Relay Slave (Distribution Master) ***should never have MyISAM and InnoDB tables present***. Suppose you run `CREATE TABLE (...) ENGINE=InnoDB;` on the Master. The Relay Slave will attempt to create the InnoDB table on the Relay Slave. If the Relay Slave has `skip-innodb` configured, it could possibly end up as a MyISAM table. You want to avoid that because it will increase disk I/O and InnoDB or MyISAM activity.

If the Relay Slave has both `skip-innodb` and `default-storage-engine=BLACKHOLE` configured, you would have to run a create table with identifying the storage engine (`CREATE TABLE (...);`).

Comment: @Mat Sorry for mix  up. I just added `not` to that statement.